# How to get solr autocomplete single keywords from description(text all) field?

Tags: json, solr, autocomplete, lucene, autosuggest

If I type (single word) in text box like : `ind`

Then it retrieves all the words starting with `ind` in below description text:

> **Description** : On the other hand, we denounce with righteous ***indignation*** and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of ***Indiana*** of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are ***indulgence*** simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour

Then it will return from the above Description all text found where "ind" contains words Like in above: `indignation`, `Indiana`, `indulgence`.  These words are all retrieved by AutoSuggest in the text box.

I tried lots of examples and Schema.xml customization but failed.

Comment: I'm confused.  So, when you type in "ind", you get the suggestions "indiana", "indulgence", and "indignation".  That sounds correct to me.  What's the problem?

Comment: I am not getting this type of value. I need to get this type of Auto Suggest word from Description text. In above, i define my task definition. I need above result from my text box input value. Like i type "Ind" than i need auto suggest word starts with "Ind". Words like "India", "Indiana", "Indulgence", "Indira". All those words starts with "Ind" from description text i retrieve single word only.

I don't have any idea how to configure auto suggest from "Schema.xml" or any other way to configure auto suggest in Solr. So i need steps, how to start or active or get auto suggest word.

Comment: Have you looked into [Solr's Suggester](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester)?